# Get all possible strings from list of letters in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

I am trying to make a python script that generates all the possible stings of lists of letters

These lists contain all the posssible letters that make up the string in order, like:

```
`
firstLetter = ["a", "s"]
secondLetter = ["e", "r"]
thirdLetter = ["w", "s"]`
```

I tried this:

```
`
import itertools

firstLetter = ["a", "s"]
secondLetter = ["e", "r"]
thirdLetter = ["w", "s"]

comfirst = list(itertools.combinations(range(firstLetter), 1))
combsecond = list(itertools.combinations(range(secondLetter), 1))
combthird = list(itertools.combinations(range(thirdLetter), 1))



comb = list(itertools.combinations(range(combfirst,combsecond,combthird), 3))

print(comb) `
```

Expected result:

aew
arw
sew
srw
aes
ars
ses
srs

Actual result:

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: what do you expect `range(firstLetter)` to *do*? Don't you just mean `firstLetter`?

Comment: The TypeError should point to the problem, and the description is exactly what it says. What do you expect `range(["a", "s"])` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```py
from itertools import product
list(map("".join, product(firstLetter, secondLetter, thirdLetter)))
```

This outputs:

```py
['aew', 'aes', 'arw', 'ars', 'sew', 'ses', 'srw', 'srs']
```

Comment: Sorry I tought it didn't work  because I didnt print it, thank you so much.